# How can I use terminal to ping a computer every 60 secs continuously, if no ping response sound an alarm

Tags: networking, mac, terminal, ping, alarm

How can I use terminal to ping a computer every 60 secs continuously, if no ping response then ping every 1 sec, if still no response after 5 one second pings then sound an alarm and continue pinging every one second (without sounding another alarm) until I get a response, then switch back to pinging every 60 seconds.

I would also like to see a count up number so I know how many successful pings I've had since I input the command like I would see if I just do a normal "ping ip".

Currently using this command which is close, but I want more. I found/adapted this command from another post on this site.

```
while :; do ping -t 2 -c 1 $1192.168.1.100 || open alarm.m4a; sleep 60; done
```

Comment: As you probably also found, this is not considered good practice.  Perhaps you should look into a better way to do whatever it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: Why would this be considered not good practice?

Comment: http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/troubleshooting/ping.shtml puts it nicely: "An extended ping is often used by the less technically knowledgeable to track 'packet loss' or 'latency'."  And if you don't own the server you're pinging, you could easily be accused of launching an attack, despite the traffic being very minimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
ip=192.168.1.100
while :; do
  ping $ip || {
    for i in {1..5}; do ping $ip && continue 2; sleep 1; done
    afplay alarm.m4a
    while sleep 1; do ping $ip && break; done
  }
  sleep 60
done
```

Comment: This seems close, however it didn't play the alarm and pings every second from the start. Any thoughts?